# Removing and re-adding a CSS property changes element's position

Tags: html, css

I'm running into something really weird with my HTML/CSS.

When I reload the page **sometimes** one of my elements ends up positioned where it's supposed to be (centered vertically) and sometimes it ends up out of the viewport (something like 700px above the top of the page).

That the page acts differently on different page loads is only half of the weirdness. If I remove `body`'s `height: 100%` property and re-add it in the web inspector everything magically fixes itself. (`body` is this element's direct parent.)

My instinct tells me that the answer to the first part of the weirdness is that there's some race condition going on causing things to happen in a different order randomly. But I'm not sure *what* that might be or why it's affecting things.

What could cause removing and re-adding an identical CSS attribute from an element to cause the page layout to change?

I can't reproduce in a jsfiddle unfortunately but here's a gif of this in action:

[image: gif]

**Edit:** A new piece of the puzzle. I've discovered that this only happens in Chrome and appears to happen *only* if the page is loaded with an empty hash on the URL.

- http://myurl.com works
- http://myurl.com/#foo works
- http://myurl.com/# **intermittently has issues**

There was a workaround to trigger a re-flow posted by @Huangism below but there are some caveats (some complications with timing when exactly to trigger a re-flow and also triggering a re-flow on a working page causes a flash of the content).

Comment: +1 nice gif demo.  Have you tried running it without developer tools open?  I ran into an issue like this a long while back and a later version of chrome corrected the issue.

Comment: when you toggle the height, chrome redraws and shows the correct content. I assume this is on chrome only. What's the url to your page? are you loading anything using js? I think this is the same chrome issue I ran into before which had a simple solution. If you can provide more code of the js loading the content I can probably give you some suggestions

Comment: Does this occur on all browsers or just chrome? +1 for the gif.

Comment: @JosephMarikle - I hadn't but good thought. Unfortunately I just tried after closing the developer tools and was still able to reproduce it.

Comment: @Huangism - I've only tried on Chrome so far so not sure about other browsers. We're using Firebase so there is some content that gets loaded and updated after the initial page load (there's also that advertisement at the bottom of the page which is probably loading some things). This is running on localhost right now and isn't setup for multiple users quite yet so can't publish it. Would be happy to provide more snippets of code; what would be useful?

Comment: @JPiiONEFOURONE - I've only tested Chrome so far; about to try Firefox to see.

Comment: Update: yes, this does appear to be a Chrome-specific issue. I cannot reproduce in Firefox.

Comment: One such case would be when changing CSS triggers a javascript event. Try pausing javascript and then toggling the CSS property.

Comment: @BradDwyer try this: after the content at the top displays (the content that's not working) hide it, check it's height then show it. I fixed mine issue with jquery so if you have jquery on your page, try that `$el.hide().height(); $el.show();`

Comment: Chrome specific? Then you could try grepping the bugtracker for Chrome.

Comment: @JanDvorak - any ideas on how I'd search for something like this? I'm not sure what's causing it and all the search terms I can think of are pretty generic.

Comment: no good search terms; sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good grief this is hacky. Would still love an explanation for exactly what's going on and the proper way to deal with it but...

After figuring out that somehow an empty hash being appended to the URL was part of the issue an acceptable workaround seems to be completely removing an empty hash if present by using the html5 history API.

My code looks something like this:

```
// when the page is ready...
$(function() {
    // if the url ends with a "#" (and the browser supports it...)
    if(window.location.href && window.location.href.indexOf('#') == window.location.href.length - 1 && window.history) {
        // clear the darn empty hash using the html5 history API
        window.history.replaceState({}, '', './');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a weird bug with chrome, try this

After the content is shown, using jquery - hide the div that contains that content, check it's height and show it

Assuming `$el` is your jquery div element

```
$el.hide().height();
$el.show();
```

Try it and see if it fixes the issue or not

Comment: This workaround does appear to work! Thanks for the suggestion. I'll leave this question open for a while to see if anyone has an explanation or fix to the root issue rather than a workaround and if not I'll accept this answer in a day or so.

Comment: "using jquery"... pls no.  Why can't we just use plain ol' javascript?  jQuery completely unnecessary for this.

Comment: @JosephMarikle OP already have jquery on the page, might as well take advantage of it

Comment: @BradDwyer It is a bug with chrome but I am not sure what it is called

Comment: @JosephMarikle if you want to use pure javascript: `el.style.display = "none"; el.clientHeight; el.style.display = "block"`

Comment: @Huangism because it's slow.  By a huge factor.  Even if it's already loaded in, this is still a performance issue and it's just as easy to run simple javascript for it.  I don't see why anyone would use jQuery for this when you already have vanilla javascript that is just as easy to use.

Comment: @JosephMarikle hmm... the DOM API doesn't have exactly nice method names... I don't like to remember which methods work in IE8 and which don't... implicit iteration is nice... You don't really care about miliseconds in code that runs once per page load.

Comment: jQuery or not: I'm trying to put this in my actual code and having trouble.. there seems to be a timing issue. If it gets called before the glitch happens then it doesn't work; putting it in a setTimeout creates a race condition (eg how long should it wait?). Also causes a slight flash if the problem doesn't happen that page load.

Comment: @JanDvorak If I am using jQuery only for nice method names, then that is sad and terribly inefficient.  You can just prototype it out if you have to.  Not liking to remember what works and what doesn't isn't going to cut it in the industry.  A good web developer knows his dependencies.  The reason why I pointed it out on this one is because I know compatibility for this is good, and you should care about milliseconds because they are the difference between dropped sites and returning customers.

Comment: @BradDwyer Have you tried putting in a window load event listener?  It's different then the typical ready state.  It occurs after everything is loaded. (I don't have the specs on this but it shouldn't be hard to find)

Comment: @JosephMarikle let me restate: The difference between assigning the style through jQuery and pulling the element out of jQuery to assign it a style is going to be below one milisecond. One milisecond is... four times shorter than the refresh period of even the best contemporary LCD screens. Twelve times shorter than that of the usual screens. Fifty times to one hundred times shorter than the refresh period of human eye. 133 times shorter than the time it takes for a light beam to reach America from China and return. I really don't care about _that_.

Comment: @JanDvorak I'll give you that, but who said it happens once?  If you establish a practice of throwing menial tasks at jQuery, you're not going to do it once.  The point is about establishing good practices vs bad.

Comment: @Huangism - I posted an Edit above, found out this is only happening if an empty hash is appended to the URL; that trigger any more ideas?

Comment: @JosephMarikle I do agree that establishing good practices is important. I still prefer readable code that clearly works over code that is slightly shorter unless I know the code might be a bottleneck. Premature optimisation is a bad practice. Also, inconsistent coding style is a bad practice, and combining jQuery with native methods might be regarded as such.

Comment: @BradDwyer automatic scrolling to ID by hash? If the page resizes, Chrome might want to reset it to some sensible values; maybe it was insensible before due to the hash?

Comment: @JanDvorak - that seems like it might be the case; another workaround looks to be `window.location.hash = 'id_of_my_element';`. What element does an empty URL hash try to scroll to?

Comment: @JanDvorak  I'll concede on that point.  Everyone develops differently and I can understand the desire for a guarantee of usability especially on a site like SO where you can't know all the environment variables for a question.

Comment: @BradDwyer I can only guess. Past the end of the page? That would hide anything but the background or fixed elements. Before the top of the page? Same symptoms, but kinda unlikely.

Comment: @JanDvorak OP mentioned it in a comment in the answer below

Comment: @BradDwyer for the flash, you could initially have a class on the div which has `visibility: hidden` and then remove that class after you do your trick. Ideally the best time to apply the script is after everything is loaded. I am not sure how your page works but maybe on window load. I don't have any suggestions for the hash, the issue I had appears when orientation changes on android tablets and another one when we tried to show a tooltip.

Comment: Thanks guys. Turns out removing the empty hash before this glitch happens is a workaround with no discernible side-effects.

Comment: @BradDwyer I am still in shock to see '15' in the top left when I returned from lunch... 15 comments

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the height using js or jquery.

It looks like when you reload the page your CSS attributes are set to your body tag via style="" and then quickly removed. Its likely something in your js

Comment: You are correct, we do have a line of jQuery that does $('body').removeAttr('style'); after the Facebook library initializes to fall back to the CSS that should be loaded from external stylesheets by that time. The CSS in the stylesheets is identical though and removing that line from the JS didn't solve the issue unfortunately.

Comment: In regard to setting the height using JavaScript, calling this does work as a workaround so it appears to maybe be a layout bug with Chrome? $('body').css('height', 'auto');
setTimeout(function() {
$('body').css('height', '100%');
}, 16);

Comment: Adding `$('body').css('height', 'auto');` isnt very usefull because you have `$('body').removeAttr('style');` running. But the setTimeout is probably your best bet unless you would rather remove all the css in the style attribute except for the `height:100% ` after the Facebook library initializes. 

Example:

'$(body).css("margin", "");' will mark margin as null and therefore remove it from the inline style attribute.

It's a bit tedious, but it should work. I do think its got something to do with the order that you are loading your css in. 

Good Luck!